# Event emitter in router-outlet for getting value from child to parent

Tags: angular

I have my parent component looks like this

```
<div class='placeholder'>
  <router-outlet (newItemEvent)="changeLoadText($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I am trying to  get some value from child component.

So in the child component Ts file I have created below function to handle the emitted event.

```
  changeLoadText(newLoadingText:string) {
    this.loadingText=newLoadingText;
  }



  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();   
  changeLoadText(value:string){
    this.newItemEvent.emit(value);
  }
```

So I am calling the above changeLoadText in few functions in the child component to update spinner text in parent.

So in parent ts file I have created below method to handle emitted event from child

```
  changeLoadText(newLoadingText:string) {
    this.loadingText=newLoadingText;
  }
```

But it shows a compile error

```
Error: src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:13:51 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

13     <router-outlet (newItemEvent)="changeLoadText($event)"></router-outlet>
```

I didnt understand what I did wrong. Is it because router-outlet is not that something to handle emitted event from child??

Comment: As you say, if you has a component in a router-outlet you can not use eventEmitter. the components has no relation child-parent. You should use a service to communicate the two components, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service) NOTE: the title is "Parent and children communicate using a service" but is a wrong title, should be "Comunicate two components using a service"

Answer (score 2):

The router outlet has two events `activate` and `deactivate` that emit your component ref.

[Angular documentation - Router Outlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

[Stackblitz - Router basic example dvsmnx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-dvsmnx)

So, In your case, If you have `loadingText` property in your child component

Child TS

```
loadingText:string = 'some text';
```

And your parent component is catching the `activate` event with `changeLoadText` function

Parent HTML

```
<div class='placeholder'>
  <router-outlet (activate)="changeLoadText($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then you can have your data using the component reference

Parent TS

```
  changeLoadText(CompRef:any) {
    let ChildText:string = CompRef?.loadingText;
    console.log(ChildText); // 'some text'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this is to use `router-outlet`'s `activate` event to get a reference to a child component, and then subscribe to its `EventEmitter` directly.

```
<router-outlet (activate)="subscribeToChildEmitter($event)"></router-outlet>
```

and then in your parent component:

```
subscribeToChildEmitter(componentRef: any) {
  if (componentRef.newItemEvent != null) {
    componentRef.newItemEvent.subscribe((newLoadingText:string) => {
      this.loadingText=newLoadingText;
    });
  }
}
```